# .after() putting the first div as the last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hay all, i have a basic big of jQuery. What I'm trying to do is take the first div from a group of div and make it become the last div in the group, the HTML looks like this

```
<div>
    <div id=1></div>
    <div id=2></div>
    <div id=3></div>
    <div id=4></div>
</div>
```

I'm im using

```
$("div div:first").after( $("div div:last") );
```

However it isn't working.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your elements backwards. The first selector needs to select the element you want to insert after and the second selector takes the element you want to insert:

```
$('div div:last').after($('div div:first'));
```

Comment: @dotty - There was a typo. I forgot to wrap the second selector in the jQuery object.

Comment: Actually, this does work. There was another issue with another area of the javascript which was making it look like it wasn't working. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your jQuery the wrong way round. You are appending the last div after the first div. So you could reorder your jQuery or another solution could be (if you have a class on the top level div)

```
$('.someClass div:first').appendTo($('.someClass'));
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be prependTo? Putting it at the end of the list?

Comment: AppendTo adds the selected elements to the end of the element in the function, while prependTo adds them to the beginning.
Its the standard meaning of append and prepend. ;-)